# Automate fetching of group id in Yammer

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, windows-phone-8, yammer

How do you get the group id in Yammer?

I am able to post a message in all of the company as well as to a specific group but i am not able to get the group id of a particular group using Yammer APIs

Find below the code for posting in a particular group where group_id is a string variable whose value I enter manually and want to automate this process.

```
private void Post(string address)
    {
        System.Uri targetUri = new System.Uri(https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json?body=HelloTest&group_id=[some_number]&access_token=" + token);
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(targetUri);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ReadWebRequestCallback), request); 
    }

// STEP4 STEP4 STEP4
    private void ReadWebRequestCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
        HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.EndGetResponse(callbackResult);
        string results;
        using (StreamReader httpwebStreamReader = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            results = httpwebStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
            //TextBlockResults.Text = results; //-- on another thread!
            SkyDriveContent test = new SkyDriveContent();
            test.Name = results;
            str_results = results;

        }
        myResponse.Close();
    }
```

I saw the documentation but did not find any way to get the list of groups a user is a part of?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to get the list of groups that a user belongs to by making a GET request to https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/groups.json?mine=1. It looks like you are using HttpWebRequest for your client code. If you haven't done so I'd suggest checking out [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) as it'll cut down on the amount of code you have to write.